# Obtener un listado entre dos fechas

Tags: php, laravel, json

Tengo creada una api restful que obtiene una lista de coordenadas que estan almacenadas en una base de datos que sigue el siguiente formato: /dispositivos/1/gpses/0, donde en primer número es el identificador del dispositivo que queremos ver y el segundo es desde que fecha queremos obtener datos, en formato Unix Timestamp. Para una fecha concreta no tiene ningún problema. Mi duda radica en si quiero obtener los datos entre dos fechas concretas. El comienzo del código lo tengo más o menos calro:

```
$fechaInicial = strtotime($fechaInicial);
$fechaFinal = strtotime($fechaFinal);
$posicionesIntermedia =  $this->obtenerUnSeguimiento($dispositivoId, $fechaInicial);
```

Y se que lo siguiente seria hacer un recorrido de `$posicionesIntermedias` descartando todos aquellos datos que sean mayores de `$fechaFinal`. Pero no se como enfocar el foreach.

Se me olvido decir que la respuesta de la api es un json compuesto por los datos `fecha`, `dispositivo_id`, `latitud` y `longitud`

¿Alguna ayuda?

EDITO: Añado el código del método obtenerUnSegumiento()

```
protected function obtenerUnSeguimiento($id, $fecha)
{
    $respuesta = $this->realizarPeticion('GET', "https://localhost/dispositivos/{$id}/gpses/{$fecha}");
    $datos = json_decode($respuesta);
    $posiciones = $datos->data;
    return $posiciones;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he arreglado.... por si sirve de ayuda, lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

```
foreach ($posicionesIntermedia as $pos)
{
    if ($pos->fecha < $fechaFinal)
    {
        array_push($posiciones, $pos);
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puesto que no indicas que hace la función obtenerUnSeguimiento(), una posible solucion seria plantear el for de esta manera:

```
$fechaInicial = strtotime($fechaInicial);
$fechaFinal = strtotime($fechaFinal);

for($cont = $fechaInicial; $cont < $fechaFinal; $cont++) {

    $temp =  $this->obtenerUnSeguimiento($dispositivoId, $cont);

    if(!is_null($temp))
        $posicionesIntermedia[$cont] = $temp;
}
```

Aqui tendrias una serie de problemas de optimizacion. Quizas debas revisar la función obtenerUnSeguimiento() y ver si puedes pasarle las fechas de inicio y  fin, y hacer una consulta con ellas.

Comment: Cierto, edito mi pregunta para que se vea como es la función obtenerUnSeguimiento()

Comment: bueno, en tu caso tampoco aclara mucho el contenido de la función obtenerUnSeguimiento()... Quizas debas plantearte un nuevo endpoint l que le pasas a mayores la fecha final y que ese endpoint te devuelva el mismo json, pero filtrado con fecha inicio y fecha fin...